# Iterating over list slice in Python not working as expected

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I've got this Python 3.5 code:

```
8  class MarkovDict:
     ...
13   def add(self, corpus=None):
14     if corpus == None:
15       return
16     prev_word = corpus[0]
17     for word in corpus[1:]:
18       self.dict[prev_word].append(word)
     ...
```

Should take `corpus` which is a list of strings.
Giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 17, in main
    bot = MarkovBot(full_markov_dict)
  File "/Users/jeremy/code/markov/MarkovBot.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.forward_dict = markov_dict.cloned()
  File "/Users/jeremy/code/markov/MarkovDict.py", line 27, in cloned
    return MarkovDict(copy.deepcopy(self.dict))
  File "/Users/jeremy/code/markov/MarkovDict.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.add(corpus)
  File "/Users/jeremy/code/markov/MarkovDict.py", line 17, in add
    for word in corpus[1:]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `corpus` object is a dictionary rather than a list. When you try to index a dictionary with a slice, it knows that slices are an unhashable type that can never be added to a dictionary, so it tells you that right away.

Comment: Thank you! I looked at my code again and realized I was passing a dictionary by accident.